# How to update polygon material if I know Id of polygon?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, czml

I am loading a CZML file in cesium. And want to highlight multiple polygons (like myid_1, myid_2, myid_3) if polygon with id as "myid" is clicked. But I am unable to process it as I am not getting the entity objects of other polygons
to process its color change.
On click handler is as below.

```
var handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);
handler.setInputAction(function(click) {
    var pickedObject = scene.pick(click.position);
    if (Cesium.defined(pickedObject)) {
        console.log(pickedObject.id instanceof Cesium.Entity);  //returns true
        var colorProperty = Cesium.Color.YELLOW;
        pickedObject.id.polygon.material = new Cesium.ColorMaterialProperty(colorProperty);
    }
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);
```

How can I get the other related polygons processed on click? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found its answer on [cesiumjs forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/cesium-dev&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&hideforumtitle=true&fragments=true&parenturl=http%3A%2F%2Fcesiumjs.org%2Fforum.html#!searchin/cesium-dev/by$20MP/cesium-dev/BM0LwqxYDxk/pNOlDRBfAQAJ).

In short:

```
viewer.dataSources.get(0).entities.getById('myid_'+i).polygon.material = colorProperty;
```